# iphone - Modal view controller disappears?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

So let's say I have a viewController named homeViewController, and another view controller named listViewController

I display listViewController on top of homeViewController as a modal.
If the user clicks the off button, and then comes back to the app the modalViewController is gone.

```
ListViewController *listViewController = [[ListViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:listViewController animated:NO];
[listViewController release];
```

**Note: Application doesn't startup from scratch when this occures and the previous state is still visible**

Comment: Very odd. I just tried the same thing with some existing code and had no issues. The only difference is I was showing a nav controller that contained a new view controller:

 UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:slNewList];
 [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:navCtrl animated:YES];
 [navCtrl release];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what the problem was.
When the user locks the screen I remove homeViewController from window

```
[homeViewController removeFromSuperview];
```

When user starts the app again I do

```
[windows addSubview:homeViewController];
```

that brings homeViewController on top of its modeal

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "off button" you mean the user locks the iDevice.

I just tried this in one of my apps and the modal view controller is still there after unlocking. My guess would be that it's something unrelated to the code you have posted. I would check your `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` method in your app delegate class and see if there's anything there that would dismiss the modal view controller.

Comment: Did u add the viewController directly into the window?

Comment: No, I present my modal view controller on top of another UIViewController just like you said you did.